# React state not updating in time for render despite async-await

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I have trouble updating React state in time for render.

All API calls are returning data, so it must be due to asynchronicity but I am unsure how to fix it.  I tried callback and spamming await at multiple spots to no avail.

Here is the gist of the code:

```
findAuthor = async (id) => {   // takes an ID and returns a name
  await API.findById(id)
    .then(res => { return res.data.name })
}
```

```
getPosts = async () => { 
  await API.getPosts({})
    .then(posts => 
        {  let authorIds = [];
           (async () => {
             for (let obj of posts.data) {
               await authorIds.push(obj.author);   // collect IDs
             }

             for (let id of authorIds) {
               let val = this.findAuthor(id);   // query for names using the collected IDs
               await names.push(val);
             }

             await this.setState({ authors: names })   // update state
           })()   // End of immediately invoked function
        }
     )
}
```

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.authors.length > 0
        ? this.state.someOtherArray.map(function (item, index) {
            return <Card
                      key={index}
                      displayName={this.state.authors[index]}  // says the value is undefined
                   />
          })
        : <p> No data </p>
      }
    </div>
)}
```

Error seems to be that findAuthor is slow to return values for the array `this.state.authors`, as its values are undefined at the time of render.

Comment: use code sandbox to provide this code

Comment: Where is this `someOtherArray` and why are you depending on `someOtherArray` to iterate over `this.state.authors` ?

Comment: Won't your this.findAuthor(id) return a promise ? You would have to use Promise.all() to resolve them ?

Answer (score 0):

Return place in async function is incorrect. Async function return can't resolve because is placed after Promise resolved.
The correct style function is look like this:

```
const findAuthor = (id) => (
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    API.findById(id)
      .then(res => { resolve(res.data.name) })
  });
);
```